# Why cassandra nodes responsible for (N-1) ranges only?

Tags: cassandra, replication, database-replication

So I was reading the Cassandra paper. In the section 5.2 (replication), below is mentioned.

> All nodes on joining the cluster contact the leader who tells
> them for what ranges they are replicas for and leader makes
> a concerted effort to maintain the invariant that no node
> is responsible for more than N-1 ranges in the ring.

Why no node is responsible for more than N-1 ranges?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, I think you're referring to Facebook's paper on Cassandra from 2009.

In that paper, there were references to Zookeeper which is used in Facebook's in-house usage of Cassandra and isn't relevant in the publicly available distributions of Apache Cassandra. Specifically, all Cassandra nodes are equal -- there is no concept of leader/followers, no primary/secondary, no master/worker.

In a single-node cluster, the one and only node is responsible for all N ranges in the ring. Extending that to a three-node cluster with a replication factor of 3, all nodes in the cluster have 100% ownership of the data so are responsible for all N ranges in the ring. Cheers!

Comment: Yes. I am referring to the same paper. So are you saying instead of N-1 ranges, all nodes are responsible for N ranges instead? Also, why the paper insists N-1 instead?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all. What I'm saying is that the paper talks about Facebook's internal usage of their distribution of Cassandra. That's not how Cassandra is used in general. It's also not relevant given it was written in 2009. Cheers!